# Finding the "deepest" child in a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, connect-by, transitive-closure-table

I need some help querying hierarchical data. Here is the single, simple, table, where `parent_id` references `id` and may be null for root entries.

```
  create table edition (
      id           NUMBER(20),
      parent_id    NUMBER(20)
  );
```

For each record in the table I need to find the deepest child having maximum id. If a record has no children, then its own id should be returned. I tried by myself but failed using `START WITH A.id = B.id` where A and B are subqueries, looks like Oracle doesn't allow such joins.

Here is the sample data:

```
     id      parent_id
   ----------------------
      1        NULL
      2           1
      3           1
      4           1
      5           4
      6           5
      7           5
```

and a sample result

```
     id      result
   ----------------------
      1           7
      2           2
      3           3
      4           7
      5           7
      6           6
      7           7
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: You can see my approach. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64350/how-can-i-select-rows-from-a-hierarchical-query-with-the-lowest-level/123299#123299

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to try

```
create table tq84_edition (
  id        number primary key,
  parent_id number references tq84_edition
);

insert into tq84_edition values (  1, null);
insert into tq84_edition values (  2,    1);
insert into tq84_edition values (  3,    1);
insert into tq84_edition values (  4,    1);
insert into tq84_edition values (  5,    4);
insert into tq84_edition values (  6,    5);
insert into tq84_edition values (  7,    5);


with x (root, id, parent_id, lvl) as (
               select id    root,
                      id,
                      parent_id,
                      1 lvl
                from  tq84_edition
        UNION ALL
               select x.root  root,
                      tq84_edition.id,
                      tq84_edition.parent_id,
                      x.lvl + 1 lvl
                 from x,
                      tq84_edition
                where x.id = tq84_edition.parent_id
)
select  root, max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl, id)
  from x
 group by root;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach I can think of, it's easier to port on other RDBMS: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da0a3/19

```
with parent(root_node, child_of, parent_id, depth)  as
(
  select id, id, parent_id, 1
  from edition
  union all
  select p.root_node, e.id, e.parent_id, p.depth + 1
  from edition e
  join parent p on p.child_of = e.parent_id
)
select root_node, max(child_of)
from parent
where (root_node,depth) in
     (select root_node,max(depth) from parent group by root_node)
group by root_node
order by root_node
```

Output:

```
| ROOT_NODE | MAX(CHILD_OF) |
-----------------------------
|         1 |             7 |
|         2 |             2 |
|         3 |             3 |
|         4 |             7 |
|         5 |             7 |
|         6 |             6 |
|         7 |             7 |
```

Now, I'm loving Oracle (and http://sqlfiddle.com too), it's very concise. Now I know what's the use of MIN and MAX in KEEP DENSE_RANK. Whereas before I don't see any utility on [explicitly specifying MIN/MAX in KEEP DENSE_RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545098/getting-first-line-of-a-left-outer-join/10545403#10545403). Now I know it has a utility, if there's some **ties** on depth, you can see who is first and last in ties by using MIN and MAX.

e.g. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da0a3/24

```
with parent(root_node, child_of, parent_id, depth)  as
(
  select id, id, parent_id, 1
  from edition
  union all
  select p.root_node, e.id, e.parent_id, p.depth + 1
  from edition e
  join parent p on p.child_of = e.parent_id
)
select root_node, 

  min(child_of) keep(dense_rank last order by depth) as first_in_deepest,
  max(child_of) keep(dense_rank last order by depth) as last_in_deepest

from parent
group by root_node;






| ROOT_NODE | FIRST_IN_DEEPEST | LAST_IN_DEEPEST |
--------------------------------------------------
|         1 |                6 |               7 |
|         2 |                2 |               2 |
|         3 |                3 |               3 |
|         4 |                6 |               7 |
|         5 |                6 |               7 |
|         6 |                6 |               6 |
|         7 |                7 |               7 |
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer seems more comfortable to me. Now I understand how much I've missed when using mysql. Btw your query can be used as a source for fast refresh materialized view, am I right?

Comment: Hmm.. I haven't delved yet in materialized view in Oracle, I can't asses if my query above is amenable for views materialization in Oracle. I have tried materialized views in Sql Server though. Materialized views is Indexed Views in Sql Server's parlance, but they are exactly the same. Sql Server's materialized views is automatic, there's no notion of fast(or slow for that matter) refresh there